# How do I include another column to search in this query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to modify a search script. Below is a part of the code that i believe currently searches for exact match for email and matches for first name and last. I also would like for it to search for matches (partial and full) in column called 'details'. What do I need to change so that it attempts all three search patterns?

```
//begin snippet

if($qt == 1) {
                $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '%s' LIMIT 1", $this->db->real_escape_string($value)));
            } else {
                $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%s' OR concat_ws(' ', `first_name`, `last_name`) LIKE '%s' ORDER BY `verified` DESC, `idu` DESC LIMIT %s, %s", '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', $this->db->real_escape_string($start), ($per_page + 1)));

                // Sometimes the query might fail due to the fact that utf8 characters are being passed and the `username` sql field does not allow special chars
                if(!$query) {
                    $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE concat_ws(' ', `first_name`, `last_name`) LIKE '%s' ORDER BY `verified` DESC, `idu` DESC LIMIT %s, %s", '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', $this->db->real_escape_string($start), ($per_page + 1)));
                }
```

Comment: why you are not using OR instead of cancat_ws ???

Comment: i didn't write this... i'm trying to figure out how it works and to modify it to include one more column in its search and do a non-case sensitive match